# What am I calling?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to check inside a fnc what is this fnc name? I'm working currently on LargeInt class and I've realized that code for oparator> and operator< is almost identical so I would like to know what operator is calling me and react accordingly.
Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733056/is-there-a-way-to-get-function-name-inside-a-c-function

Comment: What am I?
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_8yPap-k_s
Sorry, couldn't resist :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem really to be asking:

"Can I know which function called me?"

If so, no, there is no built in way of doing this, and it would IMHO be bad design to do this. You can however certainly implement the `op<` and `op>` (and the other relational operators) in terms of one another:

```
bool operator < ( A a1, A a2 ) {
    return a1.x < a2.x;     // base implementation
}

bool operator==( A a1, A a2 ) {
    return !(a1 < a2) && !(a2 < a1);
}

bool operator>( A a1, A a2 ) {
    return !(a1 == a2) && ! (a1 < a2 );
}
```

and so on.

Comment: ummm... `inline bool operator>(A a1, A a2) { return a2 < a1; }`

Comment: In fact you only need to implement operator< and operator== (the latter possibly in terms of the former). All other operators are implemented on top of those two, readily availabl ein the `rel_ops` namespace of the `utility` header file.

Comment: @Neil yes just before second it came to me head ;)

Comment: Of course, just because `!(a1 < a2) && !(a2 < a1)` is true [doesn't mean they are equal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).

Answer (score 6):

You can pass `__func__` (C99) or `__FUNCTION__` or `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` (non-standard).

There's no standard and reliable way to find the name of the caller of the function, if the caller doesn't provide the `__func__` (imagine an inlined function with all symbols stripped).

But it's better to just refactor the common part into a standalone function if that bothers you.

```
int compare(const T& other) const { ... }

bool operator< (const T& other) const { return compare(other) < 0; }
bool operator> (const T& other) const { return compare(other) > 0; }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, not without running inside an interactive debugger.

A compiled and linked C++ program doesn't necessarily include all the symbol information, so if you just broke somewhere in the stack and was able to trace the addresses of all the invoking functions you would have a hard time translating these addresses back to meaningful names. This is a big difference from, say, Java, where methods names can be reported by the program.

An interactive debugger, on the other hand, will be able to make the connection for you.

Comment: I'd rather do without the names of the fnc then touch Java outside of my study. Ughhh...

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard or portable solution, but you might be interested in [backtrace()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/backtrace.3.html), if you are developing on Linux.

Nevertheless, I think your comparison function should work the same regardless of who does it call.

Answer (score 0):

Put the common code into a new method, and call it with an additional parameter distinguishing calls from the `operator<` and `operator>` methods.

```
bool LargeInt::almost_identical(LargeInt const &rhs, enum Caller caller)
{
    ...alleged almost identical code...
}

bool LargeInt::operator>(LargeInt const &rhs)
{
    return almost_identical(rhs, CALLER_GT);
}

bool LargeInt::operator<(LargeInt const &rhs)
{
    return almost_identical(rhs, CALLER_LT);
}
```