# Export function from DLL in Visual Studio 2010 using DEF

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I inherited a **huge C++** multi-project solution with many dynamic libraries but **without any**

```
__declspec(dllexport)
```

I [learned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx) that one does not necessarily have to insert any *dllexport* (would be much work) but that one can use a *.def* file in addition to corresponding *.dll* instead.

In order to try that I built a "DLL Hello World" project from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235636.aspx), removed the *dllexport* from the header and...failed desperately. In the words of already [cited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx) page, my **key question** is how to

```
"[..] use the .def file when building the DLL."
```

My *.def* file is (I try the code only with the *Add* method):

```
LIBRARY   MathFuncsDll
EXPORTS 
?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z
```

How do I use it when building the DLL in Visual Studio 2010 in order to export the *Add* method?

Comment: Can you show the prototype to your `Add` function?

Comment: `static double Add(double a, double b);`, placed as `public` in class `MyMathFuncs` of namespace `MathFuncs`

Comment: Are you exporting the class?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186232/exporting-dll-c-class-question-about-def-file

Comment: No, I don't but thank You for the hint anyway.

Comment: Do you want to export pure-C interface functions from the DLL?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand Your question, Mr.C64. I use C++. What would be (im)pure?

Comment: Win32's [`GetWindowText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx) is an example of a "pure C interface" function exported from a DLL. You use `extern "C"`, you don't use C++ objects at the interface, you don't throw C++ exceptions outside the function, etc. (The implementation can be in C++, but the interface is pure C.) But it seems you want to export a C++ class (static) method...

Comment: Thanks a lot for Your effort to teach me, Mr.C64. In this case, interface functions are impure in given projects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After having passed half a day in front of this problem, I just found the solution: **it is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34c30xs1.aspx).**

To resume the **process of symbol export with *.def* files in VS2010** using my own words:

1. Tell VS2010 to compile a dynamic library (.dll). This is done in the **Property Page** of the library's project.
2. Craft a module definition file (.def) by using [*mangled* (decorated) names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ax8kbk1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (at least when Your language is C++). If You make use of *dllexport* You can display already exported symbols of Your .dll as [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b06ww5dd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). If You haven't anything exported yet, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190326/c-finding-out-decorated-names?lq=1) post.
3. Add the .def to the library definition in its **Property Page**.
4. Compile
5. Verify the correctness of Your work, for example with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) by opening the dependent file, e.g. *.exe*. You should see the just compiled library in a dependency tree below the dependent file. There should be no errors or warnings, e.g. *no red colour*.

If You have further questions concerning *.def* files, look out for the terminus **"Module definition file"**.

Comment: The whole point of __declspec is that you don't have to do 2, 3 and 5.  You only really use a .def file if you want to *rename* the exports.

Comment: In my case I was **reluctant to add** _dllexport_ in hundreds of files of already existing code. In particular because it may change in the future (not my changes). That code is developped for MinGW, actually. My **hope** is **to automate exports without any code changes.**

Comment: That naturally leads to the next obvious question: How to determine '_mangled_' names like `?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z` for arbitrary classes and methods? In my specific case, I cheated: I created a .dll **with** _dllexport_ first, extracted the symbol, then crafted the .def with extracted symbol and, finally, removed _dllexport_ again. How can a _mangled_ name be determined in a general case?

Comment: Right, you got it complete backwards.  dllexport ensures that the mangled name is correct, even after changes.  You could use a map.